# With a mongoose .update query, can you refer to the fetched record in the update parameter?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to something like this with Mongoose or even just Mongo?

`Center.update({ghostBuster:{$exists}},{$set:{ectoplasm: this.exoplasm},$unset: {exoplasm:""}}, function(err, result){ })`

I would like to update a number of records and move one field into another field, so if I could refer to that fetched record as I update it. In this case I'm making the `ectoplasm` field have the value of `exoplasm`

Is it possible to do this without defining a hook on the Mongoose Schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With mongo you can do this by iterating the cursor returned from the find query (using [**`forEach()`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) method) and update the collection within the loop. For example:

```
db.centers.find({ 
    "ghostBuster": { "$exists": true } 
}).forEach(function(doc){
    db.centers.update(
        { "_id": doc._id },
        {
            "$set": { "ectoplasm": doc.exoplasm },
            "$unset": { "exoplasm": "" }
        }
    )
});
```

This "back and forth" to the server is going to cost in IO, so you would try to minimize it. Use **[`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/)** method (if using MongoDB version 3.2) to do the updates in bulk:

```
var ops = [];

db.centers.find({ 
    "ghostBuster": { "$exists": true } 
}).forEach(function(doc) {
    ops.push({
        "updateOne": {
            "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
            "update": {
                "$set": { "ectoplasm": doc.exoplasm },
                "$unset": { "exoplasm": "" }
            }
        }
    });

    if (ops.length === 1000) {
        db.centers.bulkWrite(ops);
        ops = [];
    }
})

if (ops.length > 0)  db.centers.bulkWrite(ops);
```

---

Or for MongoDB 2.6.x and 3.0.x releases use this version of **[Bulk operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/core/bulk-write-operations/#bulk-methods)**:

```
var bulk = db.centers.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(),
    counter = 0;

db.centers.find({ 
    "ghostBuster": { "$exists": true } 
}).forEach(function(doc) {
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
        "$set": { "ectoplasm": doc.exoplasm },
        "$unset": { "exoplasm": "" }
    });

    if (counter % 1000 === 0) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.centers.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
});

if (counter % 1000 !== 0 )  bulk.execute();
```

The Bulk operations API in both cases will help reduce the IO load on the server by sending the requests only once in every 1000 documents in the collection to process.

---

For the Mongoose equivalent, you can implement something like the following which uses Promises to handle the async nature of the bulk API in node.js. 
In order to use the underlying bulk operations API, you should access it via the `.collection` property from the mongoose model. Before using the API, wait for mongoose to successfully connect to the db since Mongoose doesn't really support the `"initializeOrderedBulkOp()"` function yet, because it doesn't work with mongoose's internal buffering system.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    express = require('express'),
    Promise = require('bluebird'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

function connect(uri, options){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        mongoose.connect(uri, options, function(err){
            if (err) return reject(err);
            resolve(mongoose.connection);
        });
    });
}

var centerSchema = new Schema({
    exoplasm: Number,
    ghostBuster: Number,
    time: Date
}, { collection: "centers" });

var Center = mongoose.model("Center", centerSchema);

/*
function bulkUpdate(Model){    
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var bulk = Model.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(),
            counter = 0;

        Model.find({ "ghostBuster" : { "$exists": true } })
            .lean().exec(function (err, docs) {
            if (err) return reject(err);

            docs.forEach(function (doc){
                counter++;

                bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
                    "$set": { "ectoplasm": doc.exoplasm },
                    "$unset": { "exoplasm": "" }
                });

                if (counter % 500 == 0 ) {
                    bulk.execute(function(err, result) {
                        if (err) return reject(err);                        
                        bulk = Model.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();                        
                        resolve(result);
                    });
                }                       
            });     

            if (counter % 500 != 0 ) {            
                bulkUpdateOps.execute(function(err, result) {
                    if (err) return reject(err);
                    resolve(result);
                });         
            }           
        });     
    });
}
*/

function bulkUpdate(Model){    
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var ops = [],
            collection = Model.collection;

        Model.find({ "ghostBuster" : { "$exists": true } })
        .lean().exec(function (err, docs) {
            if (err) return reject(err);

            docs.forEach(function (doc){
                ops.push({
                    "updateOne": {
                        "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
                        "update": {
                            "$set": { "ectoplasm": doc.exoplasm },
                            "$unset": { "exoplasm": "" }
                        }
                    }
                });

                if (ops.length === 1000) {
                    collection.bulkWrite(ops, function(err, result) {
                        if (err) return reject(err);                        
                        ops = [];
                        resolve(result);
                    });
                }                       
            });     

            if (ops.length > 0) {            
                collection.bulkWrite(ops, function(err, result) {
                    if (err) return reject(err);
                    resolve(result);
                });         
            }           
        });     
    });
}


connect('mongodb://localhost/test', {}).then(function(db){
    bulkUpdate(Center).then(function(res){
        console.log('Bulk update complete.', res);      
    }, function(err){
        console.log('Bulk Error:', err);
        db.close();
    });
}, function(err){
    console.log('DB Error:', err);
});
```